# Как на си в линуксе проверить входную строку на служебные символы?

Tags: linux, c, unix

Пишу прогу для обработки входных, и у меня там есть проверка на кавычки. Только вот как определить является ли символ служебным? (\n, ")

Comment: Для начала определиться, что такое служебные символы. Почему вы считаете \n и " служебными?

Comment: служебные символы **bash** сам интерпретирует и функции передаёт уже результат, как строку. Никаких служебных символов ваша прога и не увидит. *Это если служебными подразумевается символы консоли...*

Comment: @AlexGlebe  а если запустить терминал на этой программе без баша?